# Push RTC snapshot from development stream to release stream

Tags: release-management, alm, rtc

I have a project with two streams, `SW_Devel` and `SW_Release`. All the day to day work happens in `SW_Devel`, which has several "Release candidate" snapshots for each release:

- Version_1_RC1
- Version_1_RC2
- Version_2_RC1
- Version_3_RC1
- Version_3_RC2
- Version_3_RC3

I'd like to copy the latest snapshot of every release into the `SW_Release` stream, so its "View snapshots" would show:

- Version_1_RC2
- Version_2_RC1
- Version_3_RC3

What is the preferred way of doing this? I suppose I could manually check out each of the "final" snapshots into a workspace, then deliver that workspace to `SW_Release` and re-create a snapshot there. Would this approach work, and is there a better way?